# I want to hang a skull on my wall

Tags: design

I want to hang a few of the [Rock Skull with Pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47990&name=Rock%20Skull%201%20x%204%20x%203%20Relief%20with%20Two%20Pins&category=%5BRock%5D#T=C&C=1) on my wall.  What parts do I need to connect the pins?

Answer (score 4):

Any [Technic brick](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=135&itemBrand=1000) (or combination of several) with 3 or more holes on the side. [Technic, Brick 1 x 4 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3701) is a best single piece that can be used to attach skull without any holes being visible.

[image]

Alternatives are:

[Technic, Brick 1 x 1 with Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6541) + [Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32000)

[image][image]

Or two of [Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3700)

[image]

If you need anything without studs, you can look into [Technic Liftarms](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=137&itemBrand=1000).